# Simple nth1 predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

With SWI Prolog, there's a predicate that finds the nth item in a list called nth1.  I want to implement my own version of the predicate but SWI's is so complicated if you look at the listing(nth1) code.  Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Thank you :).

Comment: Clarify what do you mean by "simpler"? Fewer lines of code? You could remove e.g. "lists:nth0_det(3, [_, _, _, A|_], A) :- !." Otherwise, the only way to make it simpler is to make it less general. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWI code is a bit complex because the predicate can be used to generate from a variable index:

```
?- nth1(Idx,[a,b,c],X).
Idx = 1,
X = a ;
Idx = 2,
X = b ;
Idx = 3,
X = c ;
false.
```

If you don't want that behavior, `nth1/3` can be implemented easily in terms of `nth0`:

```
nth1(Idx,List,X) :-
    Idx0 is Idx-1,
    nth0(Idx0,List,X).
```

**Edit**: it's also possible to do without `nth0` in just a few lines of code:

```
nth1(1,[X|_],X) :- !.
nth1(Idx,[_|List],X) :-
    Idx > 1,
    Idx1 is Idx-1,
    nth1(Idx1,List,X).
```

Comment: Thanks larsmans, I don't want to use any nth predicates though, I've posted my solution, what do you think?  Thanks for the post.

Comment: @shuyin, I also posted an `nth0`-less solution.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using finite domain constraints for general (reversible) integer arithmetic:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

nth1(1, [E|_], E).
nth1(N, [_|Xs], E) :-
        N #> 1,
        N #= N1 + 1,
        nth1(N1, Xs, E).
```

Comment: This has the same infinite recursion problem as shuyin's solution and not very efficient. +1 for elegance though. (Still, I'd add a constraint `N #> 1`, and maybe a cut, for efficiency.)

Comment: Yes, adding N #> 1 to the second clause is a good idea, I think this removes the infinite recursion you meant, i.e., for queries like ?- nth1(3, Es, X)? Adding a cut to the first clause though would eliminate valid solutions for example for the most general query ?- nth1(N, Ls, E) and thus make the predicate incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't mean to be contradictory or get someone else to do my work actually; I just wanted some advice, sorry for not being clearer.

I've implemented it myself now but could you guys possibly suggest improvements or better ways of doing it? What I often find myself doing in Prolog is writing a predicate with say a counter or set of counters and getting a predicate with fewer arguments to call the clauses with extra arguments. This often ends up producing quite a bit of code. Anyway, here's my implementation I just did:

```
item_at( N, L, Item ) :-
    item_at( N, 0, L, Item ).   
item_at( N, Count, [H|_], Item ) :-
    CountNew is Count + 1,
    CountNew = N,
    Item = H.
item_at( N, Count, [_|T], Item ) :-
    CountNew is Count + 1,
    item_at( N, CountNew, T, Item ).
```

Any comments?  Thanks :).  Usage:

```
?- item_at(3,[a,b,c,d,e],Item).
Item = c ;
```

Comment: +1, this version is quite general (although it might go into infinite recursion on backtracking/generating). One suggestion, the second clause can be much shorter: `item_at(N,Count,[H|_],H) :- N is Count+1.`

Comment: Thanks larsmans, that's a nice improvement, thanks very much for that :).  Tested and working and I can see how :).