# How do I implement GNU Prolog's nth(X,List,Item)?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to use an API that's mostly compatible with GNU Prolog. Unfortunately the GNU Prolog predicate nth(X,List,Item) is not there.

How would you implement nth using ISO predicates?

Description: nth(X,List,Item) evaluates to true, if the Xth item in List is Item.

I am stumped again. Please help.

Thanks upfront.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237697/simple-nth1-predicate-in-prolog

Answer (score 3):

see this pl file with  `nth0(+N, ?List, ?Elem, ?Rest)`:

```
%   Purpose: list processing utilities
%   This module requires
%   select/3    (from SetUtl.Pl) for perm/2
%   listtoset/2 (from SetUtl.Pl) for remove_dups/2
%   If you don't want those routines, it can be used on its own.
%   I am not sure how much of the original code was by Bob Welham
%   and how much by Lawrence Byrd.  The layout and comments are by
%   R.A.O'Keefe, as are nth*, same_length, shorter_list, and subseq*.
%   Keys_and_values has moved to PROJEC.PL.

:- public
    append/3,           %   List x List -> List
    correspond/4,           %   Elem <- List x List -> Elem
    delete/3,           %   List x Elem -> List
    last/2,             %   List -> Elem
    nextto/3,           %   Elem, Elem <- List
    nmember/3,          %   Elem <- Set -> Integer
    nmembers/3,         %   List x Set -> Set
    nth0/3,             %   Integer x List -> Elem
    nth0/4,             %   Integer x List -> Elem x List
    nth1/3,             %   Integer x List -> Elem
    nth1/4,             %   Integer x List -> Elem x List
    numlist/3,          %   Integer x Integer -> List
    perm/2,             %   List -> List
    perm2/4,            %   Elem x Elem -> Elem x Elem
    remove_dups/2,          %   List -> Set
    rev/2,              %   List -> List
    reverse/2,          %   List -> List
    same_length/2,          %   List x List ->
    select/4,           %   Elem x List x Elem -> List
    shorter_list/2,         %   List x List ->
    subseq/3,           %   List -> List x List
    subseq0/2,          %   List -> List
    subseq1/2,          %   List -> List
    sumlist/2.          %   List -> Integer

:- mode
    append(?, ?, ?),
    correspond(?, +, +, ?),
    delete(+, +, -),
    last(?, ?),
    nextto(?, ?, ?),
    nmember(?, +, ?),
    nmembers(+, +, -),
    nth0(+, +, ?),
    nth0(+, ?, ?, ?),
    nth1(+, +, ?),
    nth1(+, ?, ?, ?),
    numlist(+, +, ?),
    perm(?, ?),
    perm2(?,?, ?,?),
    remove_dups(+, ?),
    rev(?, ?),
    reverse(?, ?),
    reverse(?, +, ?),
    same_length(?, ?),
    select(?, ?, ?, ?),
    shorter_list(?, +),
    subseq(?, ?, ?),
    subseq0(+, ?),
    subseq1(+, ?),
    sumlist(+, ?),
    sumlist(+, +, ?).


%   append(Prefix, Suffix, Combined)
%   is true when all three arguments are lists, and the members of Combined
%   are the members of Prefix followed by the members of Suffix.  It may be
%   used to form Combined from a given Prefix and Suffix, or to take a given
%   Combined apart.  E.g. we could define member/2 (from SetUtl.Pl) as
%   member(X, L) :- append(_, [X|_], L).

append([], L, L).
append([H|T], L, [H|R]) :-
    append(T, L, R).



%   correspond(X, Xlist, Ylist, Y)
%   is true when Xlist and Ylist are lists, X is an element of Xlist, Y is
%   an element of Ylist, and X and Y are in similar places in their lists.

correspond(X, [X|_], [Y|_], Y) :- !.
correspond(X, [_|T], [_|U], Y) :-
    correspond(X, T, U, Y).

%   delete(List, Elem, Residue)
%   is true when List is a list, in which Elem may or may not occur, and
%   Residue is a copy of List with all elements equal to Elem deleted.

delete([], _, []) :- !.
delete([Kill|Tail], Kill, Rest) :- !,
    delete(Tail, Kill, Rest).
    delete([Head|Tail], Kill, [Head|Rest]) :- !,
        delete(Tail, Kill, Rest).

%   last(Last, List)
%   is true when List is a List and Last is its last element.  This could
%   be defined as last(X,L) :- append(_, [X], L).

last(Last, [Last]) :- !.
last(Last, [_|List]) :-
    last(Last, List).

%   nextto(X, Y, List)
%   is true when X and Y appear side-by-side in List.  It could be written as
%   nextto(X, Y, List) :- append(_, [X,Y], List).
%   It may be used to enumerate successive pairs from the list.

nextto(X,Y, [X,Y|_]).
nextto(X,Y, [_|List]) :-
    nextto(X,Y, List).

%   nmember(Elem, List, Index) Possible Calling Sequences
%   nmember(+,+,-) or nmember(-,+,+) or nmember(-,+,-).
%   True when Elem is the Indexth member of List.
%   It may be used to select a particular element, or to find where some
%   given element occurs, or to enumerate the elements and indices togther.

nmember(Elem, [Elem|_], 1).
nmember(Elem, [_|List], N) :-
    nmember(Elem, List, M),
        N is M+1.

% nmembers(+Indices, +Answers, -Ans) or nmembers(-Indices, +Answers, +Ans)
% (But not nmembers(-,+,-), it loops.)
% Like nmember/3 except that it looks for a list of arguments in a list
% of positions.
% eg.   nmembers([3,5,1], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h], [c,e,a]) is true 

nmembers([], _, []).
nmembers([N|Rest], Answers, [Ans|RestAns]) :-
    nmember(Ans, Answers, N),
        nmembers(Rest, Answers, RestAns).

%   nth0(+N, +List, ?Elem) is true when Elem is the Nth member of List,
%   counting the first as element 0.  (That is, throw away the first
%   N elements and unify Elem with the next.)  It can only be used to
%   select a particular element given the list and index.  For that
%   task it is more efficient than nmember.
%   nth1(+N, +List, ?Elem) is the same as nth0, except that it counts from
%   1, that is nth(1, [H|_], H).

nth0(0, [Head|_], Head) :- !.

nth0(N, [_|Tail], Elem) :-
    nonvar(N),
    M is N-1,
    nth0(M, Tail, Elem).

nth0(N,[_|T],Item) :-       % Clause added KJ 4-5-87 to allow mode
    var(N),         % nth0(-,+,+)
    nth0(M,T,Item),
    N is M + 1.


nth1(1, [Head|_], Head) :- !.

nth1(N, [_|Tail], Elem) :-
    nonvar(N),
    M is N-1,           % should be succ(M, N)
    nth1(M, Tail, Elem).

nth1(N,[_|T],Item) :-       % Clause added KJ 4-5-87 to allow mode
    var(N),         % nth1(-,+,+)
    nth1(M,T,Item),
    N is M + 1.

%   nth0(+N, ?List, ?Elem, ?Rest) unifies Elem with the Nth element of List,
%   counting from 0, and Rest with the other elements.  It can be used
%   to select the Nth element of List (yielding Elem and Rest), or to 
%   insert Elem before the Nth (counting from 1) element of Rest, when
%   it yields List, e.g. nth0(2, List, c, [a,b,d,e]) unifies List with
%   [a,b,c,d,e].  nth1 is the same except that it counts from 1.  nth1
%   can be used to insert Elem after the Nth element of Rest.

nth0(0, [Head|Tail], Head, Tail) :- !.

nth0(N, [Head|Tail], Elem, [Head|Rest]) :-
    nonvar(N),
    M is N-1,
    nth0(M, Tail, Elem, Rest).

nth0(N, [Head|Tail], Elem, [Head|Rest]) :-  % Clause added KJ 4-5-87
    var(N),                 % to allow mode
    nth0(M, Tail, Elem, Rest),      % nth0(-,+,+,?).
    N is M+1.


nth1(1, [Head|Tail], Head, Tail) :- !.

nth1(N, [Head|Tail], Elem, [Head|Rest]) :-
    nonvar(N),
    M is N-1,
    nth1(M, Tail, Elem, Rest).

nth1(N, [Head|Tail], Elem, [Head|Rest]) :-  % Clause added KJ 4-5-87
    var(N),                 % to allow mode
    nth1(M, Tail, Elem, Rest),      % nth1(-,+,+,?).
    N is M+1.

%   numlist(Lower, Upper, List)
%   is true when List is [Lower, ..., Upper]
%   Note that Lower and Upper must be integers, not expressions, and
%   that if Upper < Lower numlist will FAIL rather than producing an
%   empty list.

numlist(Upper, Upper, [Upper]) :- !.
numlist(Lower, Upper, [Lower|Rest]) :-
    Lower < Upper,
    Next is Lower+1,
    numlist(Next, Upper, Rest).



%   perm(List, Perm)
%   is true when List and Perm are permutations of each other.  Of course,
%   if you just want to test that, the best way is to keysort/2 the two
%   lists and see if the results are the same.  Or you could use list_to_bag
%   (from BagUtl.Pl) to see if they convert to the same bag.  The point of
%   perm is to generate permutations.  The arguments may be either way round,
%   the only effect will be the order in which the permutations are tried.
%   Be careful: this is quite efficient, but the number of permutations of an
%   N-element list is N!, even for a 7-element list that is 5040.

perm([], []).
perm(List, [First|Perm]) :-
    select(First, List, Rest),  %  tries each List element in turn
    perm(Rest, Perm).



%   perm2(A,B, C,D)
%   is true when {A,B} = {C,D}.  It is very useful for writing pattern
%   matchers over commutative operators.  It is used more than perm is.

perm2(X,Y, X,Y).
perm2(X,Y, Y,X).

%   remove_dups(List, Pruned)
%   removes duplicated elements from List.  Beware: if the List has
%   non-ground elements, the result may surprise you.

remove_dups(List, Pruned) :-
    sort(List, Pruned).

%   reverse(List, Reversed)
%   is true when List and Reversed are lists with the same elements
%   but in opposite orders.  rev/2 is a synonym for reverse/2.

rev(List, Reversed) :-
    reverse(List, [], Reversed).

reverse(List, Reversed) :-
    reverse(List, [], Reversed).

reverse([], Reversed, Reversed).
reverse([Head|Tail], Sofar, Reversed) :-
    reverse(Tail, [Head|Sofar], Reversed).


%   same_length(?List1, ?List2)
%   is true when List1 and List2 are both lists and have the same number
%   of elements.  No relation between the values of their elements is
%   implied.
%   Modes same_length(-,+) and same_length(+,-) generate either list given
%   the other; mode same_length(-,-) generates two lists of the same length,
%   in which case the arguments will be bound to lists of length 0, 1, 2, ...

same_length([], []).
same_length([_|List1], [_|List2]) :-
    same_length(List1, List2).

%   select(X, Xlist, Y, Ylist)
% >> NB  This is select/4, not select/3 !!
%   is true when X is the Kth member of Xlist and Y the Kth element of Ylist
%   for some K, and apart from that Xlist and Ylist are the same.  You can
%   use it to replace X by Y or vice versa.

select(X, [X|Tail], Y, [Y|Tail]).
select(X, [Head|Xlist], Y, [Head|Ylist]) :-
    select(X, Xlist, Y, Ylist).

%   shorter_list(Short, Long)
%   is true when Short is a list is strictly shorter than Long.  Long
%   doesn't have to be a proper list provided it is long enough.  This
%   can be used to generate lists shorter than Long, lengths 0, 1, 2...
%   will be tried, but backtracking will terminate with a list that is
%   one element shorter than Long.  It cannot be used to generate lists
%   longer than Short, because it doesn't look at all the elements of the
%   longer list.

shorter_list([], [_|_]).
shorter_list([_|Short], [_|Long]) :-
    shorter_list(Short, Long).



%   subseq(Sequence, SubSequence, Complement)
%   is true when SubSequence and Complement are both subsequences of the
%   list Sequence (the order of corresponding elements being preserved)
%   and every element of Sequence which is not in SubSequence is in the
%   Complement and vice versa.  That is,
%   length(Sequence) = length(SubSequence)+length(Complement), e.g.
%   subseq([1,2,3,4], [1,3,4], [2]).  This was written to generate subsets
%   and their complements together, but can also be used to interleave two
%   lists in all possible ways.  Note that if S1 is a subset of S2, it will
%   be generated *before S2 as a SubSequence and *after it as a Complement.

subseq([], [], []).
subseq([Head|Tail], Sbsq, [Head|Cmpl]) :-
    subseq(Tail, Sbsq, Cmpl).
subseq([Head|Tail], [Head|Sbsq], Cmpl) :-
    subseq(Tail, Sbsq, Cmpl).



%   subseq0(Sequence, SubSequence)
%   is true when SubSequence is a subsequence of Sequence, but may
%   be Sequence itself.   Thus subseq0([a,b], [a,b]) is true as well
%   as subseq0([a,b], [a]).

%   subseq1(Sequence, SubSequence)
%   is true when SubSequence is a proper subsequence of Sequence,
%   that is it contains at least one element less.

%   ?- setof(X, subseq0([a,b,c],X), Xs).
%   Xs = [[],[a],[a,b],[a,b,c],[a,c],[b],[b,c],[c]] 
%   ?- bagof(X, subseq0([a,b,c,d],X), Xs).
%   Xs = [[a,b,c,d],[b,c,d],[c,d],[d],[],[c],[b,d],[b],[b,c],[a,c,d],
%     [a,d],[a],[a,c],[a,b,d],[a,b],[a,b,c]] 

subseq0(List, List).

subseq0(List, Rest) :-
    subseq1(List, Rest).


subseq1([_|Tail], Rest) :-
    subseq0(Tail, Rest).

subseq1([Head|Tail], [Head|Rest]) :-
    subseq1(Tail, Rest).

%   sumlist(Numbers, Total)
%   is true when Numbers is a list of integers, and Total is their sum.

sumlist(Numbers, Total) :-
    sumlist(Numbers, 0, Total).

sumlist([], Total, Total).
sumlist([Head|Tail], Sofar, Total) :-
    Next is Sofar+Head,
    sumlist(Tail, Next, Total).
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two `nth` predicates: `nth0/3` and `nth1/3`.
You can read what they did in `help(nth0)` and `help(nth1)`.

So answer on your question is

```
nth( X, List, Item ) :-
    nth1( X, List, Elem ), !.
```

You may use and may not use `!` - whatever you want.

But there is no point to make such overhead predicates - it's better to use default ones.

Comment: `nth1/3` does not exist in ISO prolog, which is the target prolog of the question.

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog is an open-source Prolog, so one solution to your question is to look at how things are implemented in SWI-Prolog. You can call the `listing/1` predicate in case you don't know where the source files are located on your machine, i.e.:

```
?- listing(nth0).
lists:nth0(A, B, C) :-
    integer(A), !,
    A>=0,
    nth0_det(A, B, C).
lists:nth0(A, B, C) :-
    var(A), !,
    nth_gen(B, C, 0, A).

true.

?- listing(nth0_det).
lists:nth0_det(0, [A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(1, [_, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(2, [_, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(3, [_, _, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(4, [_, _, _, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(5, [_, _, _, _, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(A, [_, _, _, _, _, _|C], D) :-
    B is A+ -6,
    B>=0,
    nth0_det(B, C, D).

true.

?- listing(nth_gen).
lists:nth_gen([A|_], A, B, B).
lists:nth_gen([_|B], C, A, E) :-
    succ(A, D),
    nth_gen(B, C, D, E).

true.
```