# Prolog- return index of an element

Tags: list, prolog

I have been stumped for 3 hours now on this problem, I need to find the index of `(A,B,C)` where `A` is the index positions of `B` in list `C` (or `-1` if not in the list). This is what I have so far,

```
indexof(A,0,[A|_]).
indexof(A,B,[_|C]):- Y is B-1, indexof(A,Y,C).
```

it gives the element at the index spot `B`, which is not what I want.

```
indexof(A,1,[1]).
```

should return `A=0;A=-1.`

I am horrible at Prolog, I've done Java my whole life, so please also provide explanations.

Comment: Can you give an example call with values for `B` and `C`, and the expected value of `A`? (Did I understand your question correctly?)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm having difficulty phrasing my question, my brain is fried. Basically, indexof(A,1,[1]). should return A=0;A=-1. As you can tell from my highly advanced code *sarcasm*, I am completely at a loss of how to do this in this language.

Comment: No kidding, Prolog takes some time to get used to. (I sure haven't gotten it yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the builtin predicate nth1/3 which can be used directly to achieve what you want.

```
indexof(Index, Item, List):-
  nth1(Index, List, Item).
indexof(-1, _, _).
```

[edited after OP rephrased question]

The first clause enumerates the index of the item in the list, and the second clause just unifies Index with -1 per OP requirement.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out what exactly nth1/3 is doing, can you please help me understand? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237697/simple-nth1-predicate-in-prolog) question which describes how `nth1/3` works.

Comment: Thanks man! I finally think I understand, at least I understand this little part.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
indexof(A,0,[A|_]).
indexof(_,-1,[]).
indexof(A,D,[_|C]):- indexof(A,B,C), B > -1, D is B+1. 
indexof(A,D,[_|C]):- indexof(A,B,C), B = -1, D is B.
```

You needed to have the base case for [] and the increment logic for -1 as well