# Prolog - Finding specific elements index

Tags: prolog

helllo
iam new to prolog and iam trying to make a function returns a specific elements index 
for example
indexof (4,[3,4,5],X)
X is 1 
any help is really appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog- return index of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848401/prolog-return-index-of-an-element)

Comment: With different arguments, this is `nth0(X,[3,4,5],4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [nth0/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3)

```
?- nth0(X,[3,4,5],4).
X = 1 ;
false.
```

If you go to the documentation [page](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3) and click on [image] it will take you to the Prolog source code that implements `nth0/3`. ([link](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#nth1/3))

Comment: i see,that was really simple, thank you so much

Comment: @hmaher Thanks for the accept vote. OK, I keep forgetting that people with low points can not up-vote. See how that works, give out some points with an accept vote and get some points back.