# Prolog check element in grid

Tags: prolog

```
grid([
[w, w, w, b, w],
[b ,b, w, w, w],
[w, w, w, b, w],
[w, b, b, b, b],
[w, w, w, w, w] ]).
```

When I have a grid like this I want to check if a cell is white. When you enter the query:

```
white(X/Y).
```

it should say true if the cell is indeed white. I made this:

```
white(X/Y) :- grid([[w]]).
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why. (I just started learning prolog)

Comment: `white(X/Y) :- grid([[w]]).` says that *`X/Y` is a white cell **if** your grid is just `[[w]]`* which, of course, is not true, correct? Your `grid([[w]])` needs to be replaced with some logic involving `X` and `Y`.

Comment: When you call a predicate in Prolog, it "matches" it to your existing predicates and facts. Here, you have a fact that defines your grid: `grid([ [ ... ], [ ... ], ..., [ ... ] ]).`. When you call `white(X/Y)` it calls `grid([[w]])`. That call to `grid`fails because you have no facts that match it. However, try some things to experiment. What do you get if you enter `grid(X).` How about if you enter `grid([H|T])` (note that `[H|T]` represents a list whose first element is `H` and "rest" or "tail" of the list is `T`).

Comment: Look up the Prolog predicate called `nth1/3` (`nth1` with 3 arguments). What do you get if you query, `grid(X), nth1(2, X, L)`? Keep in mind what `grid(X)` yields.

Comment: And here's an interesting query: `nth1(N, [w, w, b, b, w], w).` This says that `w` is the `N`-th element of list `[w, w, b, b, w]`.

Comment: Why do you expect `white(X/Y) :- grid([[w]]).` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, I figured it out.

```
 white(X/Y) :-
        grid(G),
        nth1(Y, G, YAxisGrid),
        nth1(X, YAxisGrid, w).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the folklore predicate [nth1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237697/simple-nth1-predicate-in-prolog):

```
white(X/Y,G) :-
   nth1(Y, G, R),
   nth1(X, R, w).
```

I get:

```
?- grid(G), white(3/2,G).
G = ....

?- grid(G), white(2/2,G).
false.
```

Comment: "folklore" predicate?

Comment: hackish tradition, folklore http://www.eps.mcgill.ca/jargon/jargon.html , 
every predicate that is for example found here http://prolog-commons.org/PrologCommons.html/c_lists.html